# How to search for contacts without a specific relation?

Tags: search, relationships, custom-search, search-builder

I'm trying to figure out how to search for contacts (individuals) that do not have a "Current Employeer" relation.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search builder should be able to give you this as it has a larger range of search operators available to you.

Head to **Search > Search builder** and then use the criteria:

**Contacts > Current Employer ID > Is Null**

That should return everyone who has no value for your current employer field.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Obviously! My search failed because I also had another criteria, "email like" and forgot that "primary" is the mail-field that is the one to use.